# openpyxl - can't add font to cell - is not known style

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am testing trying to add a background color to any cells that have the words `ultrasound` as the value. I am using `openpyxl`

So far I have:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import  PatternFill, colors

my_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None,
                 start_color='FFFFFFFF',
                end_color='FF000000')
wb = load_workbook('TestTemplate.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for row in range(1,ws.max_row):
    for col in range(1,ws.max_column):
        c = ws.cell(row = row, column = col)
        if c.value == "Ultrasound":
            c.style = my_fill
wb.save("testfont.xlsx")
```

however it errors at line `c.style = my_fill` saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execelpytesttim.py", line 16, in <module>
    c.style = my_fill
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/openpyxl/styles/styleable.py", line 85, in __set__
    raise ValueError("{0} is not a known style".format(value))
ValueError: <openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill object>
Parameters:
patternType=None, fgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='FFFFFFFF', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb', bgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='FF000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb' is not a known style
```

I tried different hex values and it still fails. If I try to change the hex values to a color value like `blue` it will give an error saying that rgb value must be hex.

Is there something I am missing to get a background color in a cell?

Comment: Try the following changes in your code

1. fill_type='solid'
2. c.fill = my_fill instead of c.style=my_fill

Comment: This was the ticket! If you want to make an answer, I will give you credit. Thanks again.

Comment: Posted it as an answer, glad it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting it as an answer: Glad it worked for you

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import  PatternFill, colors
# changed fill_type from None to 'solid'
my_fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid',
                 start_color='FFFFFFFF',
                end_color='FF000000')
wb = load_workbook('TestTemplate.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for row in range(1,ws.max_row):
    for col in range(1,ws.max_column):
        c = ws.cell(row = row, column = col)
        if c.value == "Ultrasound":
            # Changed c.style = my_fill to following
            c.fill = my_fill
wb.save("testfont.xlsx")
```

Comment: I'm sure this worked previously. But as of 2022-10-14. this code does not work anymore.